# Include directory of docker-compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I run `docker-compose` with the base `docker-compose.yml` and a whole directory of docker-compose files.

Like if I had this directory structure:

```
parentdir
    docker-compose.yml
    folder1/
        foo.yml
        bar.yml
    folder2/
        foo.yml
        other.yml
```

How can I specify which folder of manifests to run when running compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best option was to have a `run.bash` file in the base directory of my project.

I then put all my compose files in say `compose/` directory, then run it with this command:

`docker-compose $(./run.bash) up`

`run.bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PROJECT_NAME='projectname'     # need to set manually since it normally uses current directory as project name
DOCKER_PATH=$PWD/compose/*
MANIFESTS=' '

for dockerfile in $DOCKER_PATH
do
    MANIFESTS="${MANIFESTS} -f $dockerfile"
done

MANIFESTS="${MANIFESTS} -p $PROJECT_NAME"

echo $MANIFESTS
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood your question well. 
You could use the `-f` flags: 
`docker-compose -f docker-compose1.yml`

**Edit** 
 
To answer your comment: no you can't `docker-compose` several files with only one command. You need to specify a file path, not a directory path. 
What you could do is create a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

DOCKERFILE_PATH=$DOCKER_PATH

for dockerfile in $DOCKERFILE_PATH
do
  if [[ -f $dockerfile ]]; then
    docker-compose -f $dockerfile
  fi;
done
```

By calling it like: `DOCKER_PATH=dockerfiles/* ./script.sh` which will execute `docker-compose -f` with every files in `DOCKER_PATH`.

([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/))

Comment: I know that, but would something like `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f folder1/* up` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple files to `docker-compose` by using -f for each file. For example if you have N files, you can pass them as follows:

```
docker-compose -f file1 -f file2 ... -f fileN [up|down|pull|...]
```

If you have files in sub-directories and you want to pass them to `docker-compose` recursively, you can use the following:

```
docker-compose $(for i in $(find . -type f | grep yaml)
do
echo -f $i
done
) [up|down|pull|...]
```